# Breadth First Search not SOLID enough

Tags: c#, algorithm, object-oriented, breadth-first-search

The following code has a modified version of the *Breadth First Search* algorithm. It not only visits the nodes, but keeps track of the paths, so I can output various messages later. I would like to make it more reusable and cut down on some of the duplicated code. There appears to be a lot of noise in it.  Here are some questions:

1. How can I refactor this code in general to adhere to more SOLID principles?
2. How can I make it so that I don't have to have a method for everything I want to do with the path (Find the shortest, find the paths with number of stops, find all paths, etc)?
3. How can I avoid the duplicated if statements when doing the console outputs?
4. Any other ideas are more than welcome?

#### **Node** class

```
internal class Node
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<Edge> Edges { get; private set; }

    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Edges = new List<Edge>();
    }
}
```

#### **Edge** class

```
internal class Edge
{

    public Node TargetNode { get; private set; }
    public double Weight { get; private set; }

    public Edge(Node targetNode, double weight)
    {
        TargetNode = targetNode;
        Weight = weight;
    }
}
```

#### **QueueItem** class

```
internal class QueueItem
{

    public Node Node { get; private set; }
    public List<Edge> Visited { get; private set; }

    public QueueItem(Node node, List<Edge> visited)
    {
        Node = node;
        Visited = visited;
    }
}
```

#### **Program** class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var a = new Node("A");
        var b = new Node("B");
        var c = new Node("C");
        var d = new Node("D");
        var e = new Node("E");

        a.Edges.Add(new Edge(b, 5));
        a.Edges.Add(new Edge(e, 7));
        a.Edges.Add(new Edge(d, 5));
        b.Edges.Add(new Edge(c, 4));
        c.Edges.Add(new Edge(e, 2));
        c.Edges.Add(new Edge(d, 8));
        d.Edges.Add(new Edge(c, 8));
        d.Edges.Add(new Edge(e, 6));
        e.Edges.Add(new Edge(b, 3));

        FindAllPaths(a,c);

        FindAllPaths(a,d);

        FindShortestPath(a, c);

        FindShortestPath(b,b);

        FindPathsWithStops(c,c,0,3);

        FindPathsWithStops(a,c,4,4);

        FindPathsWithDistances(c,c,30);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void FindPathsWithDistances(Node startNode, Node endNode, int maxWeight)
    {
        var paths = new List<Tuple<string, int, double>>();

        var queue = new Queue<QueueItem>();

        queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(startNode, new List<Edge>()));

        GetAllPaths(startNode, endNode, queue, paths);


        var foundPaths = paths.Where(path => path.Item3 < maxWeight).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("The number of trips from '{0}' to '{1}' with a distance of less than {2} is {3}", startNode.Name, endNode.Name, maxWeight, foundPaths.Count);


        foreach (var foundPath in foundPaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foundPath.Item1);
        }

    }

    private static void FindShortestPath(Node startNode, Node endNode)
    {
        var paths = new List<Tuple<string, int,double>>();
        Tuple<string, int, double> shortestPath = null;
        double shortestPathWeight = double.PositiveInfinity;


        var queue = new Queue<QueueItem>();

        queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(startNode, new List<Edge>()));

        GetAllPaths(startNode, endNode, queue, paths);

        if (paths.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {

                if (path.Item3 < shortestPathWeight)
                {
                    shortestPathWeight = path.Item3;
                    shortestPath = path;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The shortest path from {0} to {1} is {2} with a distance of {3}", startNode.Name,
                endNode.Name, shortestPath.Item1, shortestPath.Item3);
        }
    }

    public static void FindAllPaths(Node startNode, Node endNode)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<QueueItem>();

        queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(startNode, new List<Edge>()));

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentItem = queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var edge in currentItem.Node.Edges)
            {
                if (!currentItem.Visited.Contains(edge))
                {
                    var visited = new List<Edge>(currentItem.Visited) {edge};
                    if (edge.TargetNode == endNode)
                    {
                        double totalWeight = visited.Aggregate<Edge, double>(0,
                            (current, visitedEdge) => current + visitedEdge.Weight);
                        var path = GetPath(startNode, endNode, visited);

                        Console.WriteLine("The distance of the route {0} is {1}",path, totalWeight);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(edge.TargetNode, visited));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void FindPathsWithStops(Node startNode, Node endNode, int minStops, int maxStops)
    {
        var paths = new List<Tuple<string, int, double>>();
        var foundPaths = new List<Tuple<string, int, double>>();

        var queue = new Queue<QueueItem>();

        queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(startNode, new List<Edge>()));

        GetAllPaths(startNode, endNode, queue, paths);


        foreach (var path in paths)
        {

            if (path.Item2 >= minStops && path.Item2 <= maxStops)
            {
                if (minStops < maxStops)
                {
                    foundPaths.Add(path);

                }
                else if (minStops == maxStops)
                {
                    foundPaths.Add(path);

                }
            }
        }

        if (minStops < maxStops)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number of trips from '{0}' to '{1}' with a maximum of {2} stops is {3}", startNode.Name, endNode.Name, maxStops, foundPaths.Count);

        }
        else if (minStops == maxStops)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("The number of trips from '{0}' to '{1}' with exactly {2} stops is {3}", startNode.Name, endNode.Name, maxStops, foundPaths.Count);
        }

        foreach (var foundPath in foundPaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foundPath.Item1);
        }


    }

    private static void GetAllPaths(Node startNode, Node endNode, Queue<QueueItem> queue, List<Tuple<string, int, double>> paths)
    {
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentItem = queue.Dequeue();
            foreach (var edge in currentItem.Node.Edges)
            {
                if (!currentItem.Visited.Contains(edge))
                {
                    var visited = new List<Edge>(currentItem.Visited) {edge};
                    if (edge.TargetNode == endNode)
                    {
                        double totalWeight = visited.Aggregate<Edge, double>(0,
                            (current, visitedEdge) => current + visitedEdge.Weight);

                        var path = GetPath(startNode, endNode, visited);

                        paths.Add(new Tuple<string, int, double>(path.ToString(), visited.Count, totalWeight));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(edge.TargetNode, visited));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static StringBuilder GetPath(Node startNode, Node endNode, IEnumerable<Edge> visited)
    {
        var path = new StringBuilder();
        path.AppendFormat("{0}->", startNode.Name);
        foreach (var visitedEdge in visited)
        {
            if (visitedEdge.TargetNode == endNode)
            {
                path.Append(endNode.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                path.AppendFormat("{0}->", visitedEdge.TargetNode.Name);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. Please see the meta question: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: @RubberDuck Ok, do I just make another question with my updated code?

Comment: As I was saying, yes you can do it. (If it is working), Recomended title "Breadth First Search not SOLID enough v2.0" Also you need to add a link to this question.

Comment: @JaDogg - I saw your comment below, but your comment here `As I was saying, yes you can do it...` wasn't indicated below, so that is why I asked if I can post the revised version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Cosmetics

At first glance, your post looks about right... until the `Program` class. But before I dig into the matter of the subject, I like to scratch the surface a bit.

#### Whitespace Consistency

Try to be more consistent with vertical whitespace. I think the `Node` and `Program` classes have it right:

> ```
> internal class Node
> {
>     public string Name { get; private set; }
> ```

#### Naming

In general, you're using good, clear, readable names, and your naming conventions follow the official C# conventions, well done!

These ones stick out like a sore thumb though:

> ```
> var a = new Node("A");
> var b = new Node("B");
> var c = new Node("C");
> var d = new Node("D");
> var e = new Node("E");
> ```

Single-letter identifiers are never a good sign. At a glance I'd recommend making an array of nodes:

```
var nodes = new[] 
{ 
    new Node("A"), 
    new Node("B"), 
    new Node("C"),
    new Node("D"),
    new Node("E")
};
```

...but this isn't ideal, *building* the nodes shouldn't be done here.

This is wrong though:

```
private static void GetAllPaths(...)
```

A method that's called `GetXxxxx` should be *returning* `Xxxxxx` - I would expect `GetAllPaths` to return *all paths*. Being `void`, I can already say that calling this method will have side-effects on the values I give it.

#### Access Modifiers

I think `internal` is overkill here, these types aren't hurting anyone being `public`. What I don't get, is why only `FindAllNodes` is `public` while every single other member of the `Program` class is `private`.

---

### SOLID

There's quite a lot of refactoring work to be done before this code can adhere to SOLID principles.

#### S. *Single Responsibility Principle*

The `Main` method in the `Program` class is doing way too many things:

- It *builds* a bunch of `Node` objects. Look into a *builder* or *factory* pattern to extract that functionality. This node-building code looks very frail and bug-prone, easy to get wrong and break.
- It contains the entire functionality, *and* makes all function calls. Because the methods being called have side-effects, the *order* in which these methods are called actually matters, and will produce different results if modified: this is called *temporal coupling*, and should be avoided.

Each `private` method (oh, and the `public` one, too) is also doing too many things - they all "do their own thing", but then they're also responsible for outputting to the console.

The first thing to do, is to change all these `void` methods for functions that return a result - and let the calling code decide how it wants to output that result.

All other SOLID principles are irrelevant at this point. Why? Because you don't *write code to be SOLID*; you *write code*, and *as you clean it up and refactor*, it *becomes* SOLID. While SRP is still taking a beating, none of the other principles are applicable.

You need to extract classes, and keep the `Program` class - and especially anything `static`, to a minimum. I would start with moving the node-building to some `NodeBuilder` class, and the should-all-be-private methods into some `PathFinder` class.

---

#### Tuples

I don't like `Tuple`. Maybe it's just me, but whenever I used it, it seemed like a missed opportunity at making a meaningful class, or more appropriately, an immutable `struct`.

This:

> ```
> new Tuple<string, int, double>(path.ToString(), visited.Count, totalWeight)
> ```

Should be written like this:

```
Tuple.Create(path.ToString(), visited.Count, totalWeight)
```

But wouldn't it be clearer to have an immutable `struct` with `PathRepresentation`, `VisitedCount` and `TotalWeight` members, so that the rest of your code can call a path representation `PathRepresentation` instead of `Item1`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, I took some of your advice and I tried to make it better. You were right about the STRUCT over the Tuple.  I did some other things as well. I posted the updated version.  I am still unclear about the Builder or Factory pattern for Nodes (I created a Graph class to build the graph).  Take a look and let me know if you see any other improvements?  Thanks again.

Comment: @xaisoft you are not allowed to update questions after receving answers, because it will invalid the answer that was helpful to you originally.

Comment: I took most of your ideas and put it to work in this second version here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/65024/54489